# TextBox Validation - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox

I am having quite a hard time with my C# Application's textbox validation. The thing is, the said textbox should only accept decimal values. so it means, there should be no letters or any other symbols aside from the '.' symbol. The letter filter, i can handle. However, i don't exactly know how I can manage to filter the number of '.' that the textbox should accept. If anybody has any idea how to do this, please give me an idea.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work!!!

modified for just one decimal

```
    private void txtType_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || (e.KeyChar == (char)'.') && !(sender as TextBox).Text.Contains("."))
        {
            return;
        }
        decimal isNumber = 0;
        e.Handled = !decimal.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out isNumber);
    }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I can do now. However, this doesn't filter the number of decimal points which the textbox should accept. it still accepts 2 decimal points. :(

Comment: This is exactlyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy what I needddddddddddddddddddd!! Thanks. now all I need to do is to study your code. :) Thanks a lot.

Wait. I can't use the backspace key? hehe.

Comment: @Kim careful however, this is not localised - some countries use commas for decimal places.

Comment: @Adam, yes I know that but this software i'm working on is just a small exercise for my class. Thanks for reminding :)

Comment: Modified it cuz it was for ints not decimals... my bad... but it should work, also you can add some logic to hanlde the minus symbol

Comment: @Luiscencio, can you please teach me this line?

`if ((e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == (char)'.') && !(sender as TextBox).Text.Contains("."))`

coz each time I modify something from it, it all goes wrong. hehe. i am trying to modify this so that the textbox can accept Backspace strokes. Hehe. Thanks

Comment: @Kim Rivera: basically it says:
 if the key pressed is backspace or '.' and there is no '.' in the textbox's text then process the keypress, if the above statement is false then we try to parse the pressed key as a decimal number and if we succed then whe handle the keypress, if it fails it will ignore the keypress. hpe its clear =]

Comment: ohhhhh... so what should i modify in order for this code to accept the backspace key even if there is already a '.' on the textbox. coz the way i see it, it can only accept the backspace key if there is no '.' on the textbox yet. hehe

Comment: @Kim Rivera: hahah you are right.. didn't see that coming =P I fixed it now

Comment: thanks, wait. :D what did you do to fix it? i wanna know :D hehehe. thanks

Comment: I removed the parenthesis, so now it will evaluate **(e.KeyChar == (char)'.') && !(sender as TextBox).Text.Contains(".")** first then the **||**

Answer (score 4):

```
decimal value;
bool isValid = decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value);

if (!isValid)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Input must be a decimal value");
}
```

Comment: Localisable, understandable, +1able

Comment: this is what my application was doing before. however, i am avoiding a lot of error messages to pop.  so i just want the textbox to be filtered. but thanks still for this :) i appreciate it. hehe

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: if you are monitoring the decimal places, simply keep a bool flag in your control to say "I've already had a dot"; subsequent dots are invalid.

Alternatively, when checking for decimal places, you can use `Contains`:

`if (textbox.Text.Contains("."))`

Also, review this sample available on MSDN (NumericTextBox):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(VS.80).aspx

Comment: yes, i've seen this and this is actually where I learned how to restrict letters and some symbols in my textbox. However, what i'm looking for is something that would  limit the textbox to accept only one decimal point.

Comment: +1 for the Numeric Text Box sample. It still needs the "I already have a decimal separator" flag, as you suggest.

Comment: @Kim I explained a simple way to flag that.  When you detect a decimal point, set your flag to true, on subsequent detections you the behave as if its not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex validation:

```
^([0-9]*|\d*\.\d{1}?\d*)$
```

This site has a library of regex validation (including numeric related) that you'll find useful:

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=decimal&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20

Answer (score 0):

Use a MaskedTextBox instead and set the mask to only accept decimals.